# Can i force linux kernel to use particular memory pages for new executable

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, loader

When i execute binary i want their stack segment to be filled with special data.
All i do is just write program that allocate huge buffer on a stack, call a lot of malloc and mmap and for example fill all this memory with 'A' character. Then i check and see that about 80% of whole memory are used by my program. Then i stop this program and start another program that just go through the stack and check values on stack. By i don't see my 'A' character anyway. Can someone tell me how can i do it?

**UPD**
Why i do is just because of one ctf. i mention task like.

```
int func()
{
    int i;
    if(i == 0xdeadbeef)
        system("cat flag");
    else
        func();
}

int main()
{
    func();
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Just to get that right: you write memory by one process, terminate that and complain that a _different_ process does not see the data the first wrote? You ever head about logical memory and process encapsulation?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves while playing ctf i mentioned trivial task like; main {int i; if(i == 0xdeadbeef) then open shell} else go recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not without making heavy changes to the kernel. New anonymous pages are always zero-filled, and even if you could fill them with something else, there would be no reasonable way you could make them carry over data from old processes. Doing so would be a huge security hole in itself.